# Green Plum Out of memory issue is coming

Tags: memory, greenplum

Green Plum Out of memory issue is coming, Ram utilization is very less but CPU utilization is very high

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Greenplum Command Center, you should have gotten licenses from Pivotal/VMware and can submit ticket to Pivotal/VMware support. 
From the chart, the cpu usages in your segments are spending most of cpu time on "sys/kernel" mode, not user mode.
1) check the OS pre-requisites for Greenplum.
2) check your IO pre-requisites for Greenplum.
3) check your networking pre-requisites for Greenplum.

If you don't know anything about those pre-requisites and use vm on public clouds, like aws,gce,or azure, Pivotal/VMware has cloud marketplace offerings that optimize those pre-requisites for you.

Comment: btw, the question is totally misleading.   You don't have memory issue here.